# Replace value in data frame if value is greater or smaller

Tags: r

I have problem manipulating data-frame in R. This is basic thing in R, but I can't find best command to do this type of things.

Dummy example

```
Var1 20 300  39
Var2 49  23  91
Var3  0 239 210
```

How can I replace value with `10` in column 2 if value is smaller than `10`;
Or how to replace all values in data-frame with `100`, if they are greater than `200`?

Comment: If you can live with a warning: `d[d > 200] <- 100`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `apply` to replace all values greater than for example 200 in a whole data.frame

```
apply(df, 2, function(x) ifelse(x > 200, 100, x))
```

Note: if any columns are not numeric, all columns will be converted to character or factor. To avoid this, you can do the following. If you have a data.frame `df` with two numeric columns, columns 1 and 2, which you want to operate on, and two non-numeric columns, which you dont want to operate on, you could do this:

```
df <- cbind(apply(df[,1:2], 2, function(x) ifelse(x > 200, 100, x)), df[,3:4])
```

Edit after comment by @GregSnow:

It may be more useful to use `lapply` in this situation.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(x>200, 100, x))
```

For anyone who didn't know before (including myself), by using `df[]` instead of only `df` the structure of `df` is kept as it was before (thanks @GregSnow for valuable information).

Comment: `2` means that I want to operate on columns?

Comment: Exactly. If you want to operate on rows, that would be 1

Comment: The `lapply` function may be better here, it does not try to convert to a matrix first.  `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(x>200, 100, x))` or `df[1:2] <- lapply(df[1:2], function(x) ifelse( x<0, 7, x))`.

Comment: @GregSnow thanks for that additional information. Is there a reason why you use `df[]` in your example (not `df`)? (I havent seen that yet)

Comment: @beginner, try both ways and see the difference.  When you use `df[]` it retains all the attributes (including class) and just replaces the content, `df <- ` replaces the entire object.