# how to replace value in columns if value is %in% vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two vectors like:

```
one <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
two <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")
```

then I have a data frame that holds the original values:

```
from   to 
A      1
2      A
3      B
F      B
C      4
D      5
6      6
```

I'd like to replace all the entries in the original df like:

```
from   to
one    two
two    one
two    one
one    one
one    two
one    two
two    two
```

I am trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833752/replace-value-in-columns-if-value-is-greater-smaller) but it works only for the first check I do and then converts all in numbers:

```
df[] <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(x%in%one, "one", x)))
```

of course this is just a fake example, in my real case, too long to report here, all values in the original df are strings

Comment: Do the values are always either in `one` or `two`? Or sometimes there are values which are in neither. Because if the first case is true, you don't really need to check both of the `one` and `two`. You could just operate only on of of them. For instance (assuming `df` columns are of class `character`) you could simply do ```df[sapply(df, `%in%`, one)] <- "one" ; df[df != "one"] <- "two"```

Comment: Good point, in my real case I have many more than two lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We place the 'one', 'two' vectors in a `list`, `stack` it to create a key, value data.frame ('d1'), loop through the initial dataset (`lapply(df1,..`) and `match` the vector with the 'values' column to get the 'index' and replace with the 'ind' column that matches the index.

```
d1 <- stack(list(one=one, two=two))
df2 <- df1
df2[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) d1$ind[match(x, d1$values)])
df2
#  from  to
#1  one two
#2  two one
#3  two one
#4  one one
#5  one two
#6  one two
#7  two two
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(from = c("A", "2", "3", "F", "C", "D", "6"), 
 to = c("1", 
"A", "B", "B", "4", "5", "6")), .Names = c("from", "to"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: apologies, but I don't get when you use the original df

Comment: @user299791  The original dataset is 'df1'

Answer (score 1):

I think that's what you were trying to do:

```
> df <- data.frame(from=c("A",2,3,"F","C","D",6),to=c(1,"A","B","B",4:6))
> one <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
> two <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")
> as.data.frame(apply(df,2,function(x)ifelse(x%in%one,"one",ifelse(x%in%two,"two",x))))
  from  to
1  one two
2  two one
3  two one
4  one one
5  one two
6  one two
7  two two
```

Or similarly, using the `df[]` trick:

```
> df[]<-apply(df,2,function(x)ifelse(x%in%one,"one",ifelse(x%in%two,"two",x)))
> df
  from  to
1  one two
2  two one
3  two one
4  one one
5  one two
6  one two
7  two two
```

Or again with `lapply`:

```
> df <- data.frame(from=c("A",2,3,"F","C","D",6),to=c(1,"A","B","B",4:6))
> df[]<-lapply(df,function(x)ifelse(x%in%one,"one",ifelse(x%in%two,"two",x)))
> df
  from  to
1  one two
2  two one
3  two one
4  one one
5  one two
6  one two
7  two two
```